# Replace null by mean of specific variable

Tags: python, pandas, replace, mean, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe named as nf having columns name as type and minutes. for the null vlaues for a specific type i want to replace with mean of that specific type only

```
ID     Type              Minute

1        A                  2              
2        A                  5
3        B                  7
4        B                  NAN
5        B                  3
6        C                  4
7        C                  6
8        C                  NAN
9        A                  8
10       C                  2
```

for the above dataframe i want to replace nan in the minutes with the mean of that specific type. for example for B i want to replace with 5 as the other two values sum upto to 10 and 2 values so 5 and similarly for C.

I have tried to use mean function but I dont have a knowledge to do it for a specific variable.

Thank for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` + `'mean'` with `transform`:

```
df['Minute'] = df['Minute'].fillna(df.groupby('Type')['Minute'].transform('mean'))
```

`transform` performs the indexing for you, so you don't have to split the operation into 2 steps:

```
s = df.groupby('Type')['Minute'].mean()
df['Minute'] = df['Minute'].fillna(df['Type'].map(s))
```